# Pregunta sobre el Confidence Interval usando gghistostats del paquete ggstatsplot

Tags: r

```
library(ggstatsplot)
library(MASS)
library(dplyr)

immer <- immer %>% mutate(production_difference = Y2 - Y1) %>% 
  select(Y1, Y2,production_difference)

head(immer)

t.test(immer$production_difference)

gghistostats(
  data = immer, ## data from which variable is to be taken
  x = production_difference, ## numeric variable
  test.value = 0 
)
```

Por qué el confidence interval de gghistostats no coincide con el confidence interval de t.test? El p-value y el t-statistic coinciden.

***Lo único que se me ocurre es q el confidence interval sea del tamaño del efecto de Cohen que está entre 0 y 1. Y q el signo negativo indique que hay una disminución. Será eso? Allí si concidiría por que gghistostats indica que el tamaño del efecto es -0.59 y el confidence interval de gghistostats es (-0.97, -0.21)***

P.S. El default de gghistostats es parametric que usa la mean. En el ejemplo uso el default:
https://indrajeetpatil.github.io/ggstatsplot/reference/gghistostats.html

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: El método t.test utiliza la distribución t de Student para calcular el intervalo de confianza para la media de una muestra cuando se desconoce la varianza poblacional. El intervalo de confianza se calcula a partir del t-statistic y del nivel de confianza deseado (por ejemplo, 95%). Por otro lado, el gráfico de gghistostats muestra un intervalo de confianza en torno a la mediana de los datos. El intervalo de confianza se calcula a partir de la distribución normal y el nivel de confianza deseado. Es posible que los intervalos de confianza no coincidan debido a estas diferencias en los métodos de

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta. El default de gghistostats es parametric que usa la mean: https://indrajeetpatil.github.io/ggstatsplot/reference/gghistostats.html

Comment: Además el t-statistic y el p-value del t.test coinciden con los de gghistostats.

Comment: Lo único que se me ocurre es q el confidence interval sea del tamaño del efecto de Cohen que está entre 0 y 1. Y q el signo negativo indique que hay una disminución. Será eso? Allí si concidiría por que gghistostats indica que el tamaño del efecto es -0.59 y el confidence interval de gghistostats es (-0.97, -0.21)

Comment: Estoy casi seguro q gghistostats está usando el mismo t.test. Sin embargo, espero que estés en lo correcto. De nuevo, muchas gracias por tu opinión.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplemente `gghistostats` no retorna los intervalos de confianza de `t.test()` ([Ver](https://github.com/IndrajeetPatil/statsExpressions/blob/eb164e800b4d5b5eb7aac75c36966919cf2785a7/R/one_sample_test.R#L66)), los únicos coeficientes que aprovecha de `t.test()` son:

```
[1] "mu"          "statistic"   "df.error"   
[4] "p.value"     "method"      "alternative"
```

Para los intervalos de confianza aplica una de estas dos posibles funciones para calcularlos, de acuerdo al parámetro `effsize.type`, `hedges_g()` y `cohens_d()`.

Puedes verificar que debería coincidir con alguno de estos intervalos:

```
effectsize::hedges_g(
  x       = immer$production_difference,
)

effectsize::cohens_d(
  x       = immer$production_difference,
)
```

Comment: Funciona! Gracias Patricio por tu respuesta! Genial como siempre!

Comment: Si es possible por favor ayúdame con esta pregunta sobre Shiny: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/581070/r-shiny-dt-c%c3%b3mo-bajar-las-columnas-y-los-filtros

Comment: Otra pregunta, si puedes ayudarme. Gracias! https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/581080/c%c3%b3mo-aplicar-un-archivo-con-columnas-y-filtros-al-diamonds-dataset