# ¿Cómo aplicar un archivo con columnas y filtros al diamonds dataset?

Tags: r

Estoy tratando de aplicar un archivo de columnas y filtros al diamonds dataset.

El archivo de columnos está en este link: https://github.com/illyabjazevic/some_columns_and_filters_diamonds_dataset/blob/main/my_variables_february.csv

Lo que he hecho es aplicar este Código para hacer un data cleaning.

Quisiera aplicar estas columnas y filtros al diamonds dataset. Pero, no quiero hacerlo manualmente.

Se me ocurre que un loop debe funcionar.

La columna V1 son las columnas que quiero del diamond dataset.
La volumna V2 son los filtros de esas columnas.

Pueden ayudarme?

De antemano, muchísimas gracias.

```
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

DF <- read.csv("my_variables_february.csv", header = FALSE)
View(DF)

DF <- DF %>% mutate(V2 = str_replace_all(V2, "\\*|\\[|\\]", ""))
View(DF)


DF$V2 <- gsub("\\", "", DF$V2, fixed=TRUE)
View(DF)

DF$V2 <- str_split(DF$V2, ",")
View(DF)

for (x in 1:nrow(DF)){print(DF$V1[[x]])}
for (x in 1:nrow(DF)){print(DF$V2[[x]])}

head(DF)

glimpse(DF)

data(diamonds)

View(diamonds)

subsetDIAMONDS <- diamonds

for (x in 1:nrow(DF)){
   print (DF$V1[[x]])
   print (DF$V2[[x]])
}
```

Hasta allí, todo bien. Después de eso intenté lo siguiente, pero no funcionó.

[image: Console]

```
 for (x in 1:nrow(DF)){
     subsetDIAMONDS <- filter(subsetDIAMONDS, DF$V1[[x]] %in% DF$V2[[x]])
 }
```

También intenté lo siguiente, que tampoco funcionó:

```
for (i in DF$V1){
  for (j in DF$V2)
  subsetDIAMONDS <- filter(subsetDIAMONDS, i %in% j)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La idea no está mal, pero el el problema es esto: `filter(subset_temporal, DF$V1[[x]] %in% DF$V2[[x]])}`, que supones se interpreta así:

```
filter(subset_temporal, cut %in% c("Fair"))
```

pero en realidad lo que estás haciendo es algo así:

```
filter(subset_temporal, "cut" %in% "Fair")
```

o bien

```
filter(subset_temporal, "color" %in% "'D', 'E'")
```

Es decir es básicamente la comparación de dos cadenas que nada tiene que ver con la columna y los valores de estas. Para solucionar la interpretación del nombre de la columna, puedes usar `!!as.name(DF$V1[[x]])`, esto transforma la cadena con el nombre de la columna en una columna real para `dplyr`, los valores del filtro también deberías "procesarlos" y transformar esto: `"'D', 'E'"` en un vector con dos elementos.

Dicho lo anterior, una solución más cómoda a mi criterio es crear una sentencia dinámica, para esto primero vamos a limpiar un poco los datos:

```
library(tidyverse)

text <- read_file("../../Downloads/my_variables_february.csv")
text <- gsub('[\\]"', "'", text)
text <- gsub('\\[', "(", text)
text <- gsub('\\]', ")", text)

DF <- read.table(text=text, 
                 header = FALSE,
                 sep=",",
                 na.strings = "")

DF

       V1                 V2
1     cut           ('Fair')
2   color          ('D','E')
3 clarity ('I1','SI2','SI1')
4   depth               <NA>
5   table               <NA>
6   price               <NA>
```

Con esto hicimos dos cosas, las columnas sin filtro las dejamos en `NA` lo que es menos ambiguo y dejamos el resto con un formato más parecido al que se usa en el `%in%`. Con esto ya podemos escribir un query dinamico:

```
no_na <- !is.na(DF$V2)
paste0("diamonds %>% filter (",
      paste0(DF$V1[no_na], " %in% c", DF$V2[no_na], collapse = ", "),
      ")") -> batch

batch

[1] "diamonds %>% filter (cut %in% c('Fair'), color %in% c('D','E'), clarity %in% c('I1','SI2','SI1'))"
```

Hemos conseguido una batch `dplyr` que incluso podremos copiar a la consola y debería ser totalmente funcional, pero, para completar, podemos tomar esta cadena tal cual y reinterpretarla como un código `dplyr`:

```
eval(rlang::parse_expr(batch))

# A tibble: 270 x 10
   carat cut   color clarity depth table price     x     y     z
   <dbl> <ord> <ord> <ord>   <dbl> <dbl> <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1  0.86 Fair  E     SI2      55.1    69  2757  6.45  6.33  3.52
 2  1.01 Fair  E     I1       64.5    58  2788  6.29  6.21  4.03
 3  1.01 Fair  E     SI2      67.4    60  2797  6.19  6.05  4.13
 4  0.96 Fair  E     SI2      53.1    63  2815  6.73  6.65  3.55
 5  0.75 Fair  D     SI2      64.6    57  2848  5.74  5.72  3.7 
 6  0.98 Fair  E     SI2      53.3    67  2855  6.82  6.74  3.61
 7  1.01 Fair  E     SI2      67.6    57  2862  6.21  6.11  4.18
 8  0.8  Fair  E     SI1      56.3    63  2885  6.22  6.14  3.48
 9  0.9  Fair  D     SI2      66.9    57  2885  6.02  5.9   3.99
10  0.9  Fair  E     SI2      65      58  2930  6.08  6.04  3.94
# ... with 260 more rows
# i Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows
```

En este caso `rlang::parse_expr(batch)` transforma la cadena en una expresión R por lo que simplemente resta evaluarla con `eval()`.

Comment: Gracias Patricio! Eres el mejor!

Comment: No sabes cuanto te agradezco tu ayuda!

Comment: Podrías decirme si en este sitio web se puede hacer preguntas sobre matematicas?

Comment: No, lamentablemente solo si tiene que ver con temas de programación. Tal vez puedas probar en https://stats.stackexchange.com/